# Error al responder correo usando la api de google

Tags: php, gmail, google-api

cuando uso la api para responder correos, todo funciona pero si agrego un adjunto marca error

```
Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Google_Service_Exception' with message '{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "invalidArgument",
    "message": "'raw' RFC822 payload message string or uploading message via /upload/* URL required"
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "'raw' RFC822 payload message string or uploading message via /upload/* URL required"
 }
}
' in C:\xampp\htdocs\crm\vendor\google\apiclient\src\Google\Http\REST.php:118
Stack trace:
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\crm\vendor\google\apiclient\src\Google\Http\REST.php(94): Google_Http_REST::decodeHttpResponse(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response), Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request), 'Google_Service_...')
#1 [internal function]: Google_Http_REST::doExecute(Object(GuzzleHttp\Client), Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request), 'Google_Service_...')
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\crm\vendor\google\apiclient\src\Google\Task\Runner.php(176): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#3 C:\xampp\htdocs\crm\vendor\google\apiclient\src\Google\Http\REST.php(58): Google_Task_Runner->run( in C:\xampp\htdocs\crm\vendor\google\apiclient\src\Google\Http\REST.php on line 118
```

este es mi código tanto para enviar y responder,

```
    if (empty($attachments)) {
        $mime = base64url_encode($mime);
        $message->setRaw($mime);
        $result = $service->users_messages->send('me', $message);
    }else{
        $chunkSizeBytes = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
        $size = strlen($mime);
        $status = false;
        $client->setDefer(true);
        $result = $service->users_messages->send('me', $message, [ 'uploadType' => 'multipart']);
        $media = new Google_Http_MediaFileUpload(
            $client,
            $result,
            'message/rfc822',
            $mime,
            true,
            $chunkSizeBytes
        );
        $media->setFileSize($size);

        while (!$status  ){
            $status = $media->nextChunk();
        }

        $client->setDefer(false);
    }
```

He estando haciendo pruebas el error se encuentra en

```
    $chunkSizeBytes = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
    $size = strlen($mime);
    $status = false;
    $client->setDefer(true);
    $result = $service->users_messages->send('me', $message, [ 'uploadType' => 'multipart']);
    $media = new Google_Http_MediaFileUpload(
        $client,
        $result,
        'message/rfc822',
        $mime,
        true,
        $chunkSizeBytes
    );
    $media->setFileSize($size);

    while (!$status  ){
        $status = $media->nextChunk();
    }

    $client->setDefer(false);
```

ya que si uso

```
    $mime = base64url_encode($mime);
    $message->setRaw($mime);
    $result = $service->users_messages->send('me', $message);
```

el adjunto llega sin problemas el detalle aquí es falla cuando son archivos grandes falla

Comment: ¿El adjunto no es demasiado grande?  ¿Has probado con un adjunto pequeño, un archivo de texto por ejemplo de pocos KB o algo así?

Comment: de echo ese era uno de mis problemas, al principio cuando enviaba correos con adjuntos pequeños no había problema, pero con mas grades ocurría un error, pero con `Google_Http_MediaFileUpload`, logre solucionar ese error, entonces el error esta en esa sección de código, lo que no entiendo es porque cuando mando un correo normal no ocurre error pero cundo respondo ocurre un error

Comment: Pero ¿tú respondes y además adjuntas un archivo o respondes a un correo que te llega con un archivo adjunto y dicho archivo se adjunta a la respuesta que envías?

Comment: respondo a un correo con un adjunto